# Criptoactivo de StackOverflow

Tags: discusión, stackexchange

¿Alguno sabe si existe una criptodivisa de StackOverflow?

O, en caso de que no existiese, es viable la creación o solicitud de creación de alguna criptodivisa basada en los perfiles, preguntas, respuestas, vistas, shares, votaciones, respuestas aceptadas, etc?

Comment: StackOverflow es una marca comercial ... no es viable por que tendrías que comprar los derechos etc etc etc ... la moneda de comercio son los puntos ...

Comment: Tuve un overflow mental tratando de entender la idea.

Comment: Si mi pregunta tiene tantos votos negativos, ¿Puedo borrarla ya que parece afectar a la comunidad?

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque afecta a la comunidad

Comment: los votos en meta significan de acuerdo o en contra de la idea expresada.... tu pregunta es valida.. solo que mas gente opino que no estan de acuerdo con lo que planteas... y para borrar la pregunta, tendria que hacerlo un moderador, pero realmente no hay nada valido que amerite borrar esta publicacion.

Comment: No veo por que deba tener negativos la pregunta, por que literal, estas preguntando 2 cosas, no esta opinando, o dando una idea de que SO deba tenerla. Incluso la respuesta a las preguntas es, no, no hay cripto y quizas no haya.

Comment: @Excorpion yo voté negativo por que no estoy de acuerdo con que intente que haya una criptodivisa.

Comment: No esta intentando que haya una, pregunto si es que hay una o si es viable la creacion de una... a lo que le responden no y ya... en ningun lado se discute el que el OP quiera que hagan una.

Comment: *es viable la creación o solicitud de creación de alguna criptodivisa basada en los perfiles, preguntas, respuestas, vistas, shares, votaciones, respuestas aceptadas, etc?* si pregunta eso, es probablemente por que quiere enviar una solicitud

Comment: No lo creo, por que ya le dijeron que no hay, y no se hará una.

Comment: Cual es la relacion entre mi motivo por votar negativo con que ya recibió una respuesta?

Comment: Yo asumo que las respuestas con votos negativo son porque no son útiles a la comunidad o la ponen en peligro o están mal planteadas (que es parte de lo anterior). No pensé que fueran polls. De ahí que yo mismo votara por cerrar mi respuesta ya que parecía un peligro para la comunidad. Si alguien está de acuerdo conmigo, podemos votar para cerrar esta pregunta.

Comment: Tranquilo c: No creo que tu pregunta sea inutil. Que no esté de acuerdo en adulterar la escencia del sitio NO hace de tu pregunta inutil.

Comment: @Dantes. Y si, si es probable que quiera enviar una solicitud para la creación de una... pero con una probabilidad del 0.01% de que quiera hacerlo. Mi pregunta era pregunta, no sugerencia, ¡Y menos una encuesta!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hay una [pregunta relacionada con el tema en Meta StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281232/integrate-cryptocurrency-tipping). Y la respuesta es: no, no hay una criptodivisa de StackOverflow y seguramente nunca la haya.

En la [respuesta de Tim Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281422/3695983) se especifican cuatro razones por las que esto es así (muy resumidas por mi parte):

1. Va en contra de la idea de la comunidad. Añadir un factor económico adulteraría la esencia del sitio.
2. Es muy difícil encontrar el modo correcto de hacerlo. Los diferentes factores que se pueden tomar en cuenta son subjetivos.
3. Existen otras plataformas que lo hacen. Flattr, Patreon, Amazon Wishlist, Paypal... muchos usuarios ponen enlaces en su perfil.
4. Su desarrollo requeriría soporte del que SO no dispone. Hay muchos reportes tal cual, incluir criptodivisas multiplicaría las necesidades.

---

Desde un punto de vista personal (no como moderador o miembro de la plataforma). La opción que veo más viable sería la #3. StackOverflow cuenta con APIs que podría ser utilizadas por otras plataformas para permitir dar *tips*/propinas de forma directa a los usuarios (más o menos como lo hacen en Brave Creators).

Veo inviable un método basado en votos porque mucha gente crearía cuentas títere (más aún de las que ya se crean sin necesidad de que haya dinero de por medio) para darse votos y conseguir más criptodivisas.

Comment: 3, y 4 me parecen excelentes. Pero en 1, la reputación ya es una especie de factor económico... eso a mi parecer. En 2, supongo que quien quisiera implementar una (yo no), podría experimentar implementando un SO en una blockchain como Dfinity. Y, en ese ejemplo, un "SO" correría en ese servicio.

Comment: @Cuauhtli no veo el factor economico en la reputación. De hecho, la gran mayoría de los beneficios que te da la reputación son respecto a la revisión del sitio.

Comment: @DanteS. Como yo lo veo, si es un factor económico porque, si bien no es monetario (SO-coin), lo veo como una especie de transacción que además produce algo en tu cabeza que te gusta, y en la comunidad que te permite presentarte en un puesto mayor de la jerarquía.

Comment: Además, algo que se me ha hecho interesante, es el hecho de que en la plataforma trabajas de a gratis para otras empresas (cuyo nombre jamás conocerás), o universidades (a las que nunca asistirás).
Un desconocido buen samaritano, dedica recursos mentales, físicos, su tiempo, parte de su día, en resolver problemas de gente en otras empresas que se tuviern en el pasado, presente, y que se tendrán en el futuro. Y a cambio recibe símbolos de aquella transacción: reputación (la moneda acumulativa y no intercambiable), u otras métricas.

Comment: El que contesta es casi como un super proletario, pero que en lugar de monedas, recibe otro token simbólico para medirse entre los miembros de la comunidad. 
Aunque sinceramente, soy de los que concuerdan que cuando se mete el dinero en una comunidad (virtual o real), las cosas salen extremadamente mal.

Comment: Creo (porque ya no recuerdo bien) que cuando planteé la pregunta, mi mente iba en el sentido de, "¿Uno puede ganarse la vida contestando (trabajando) en SO, sin utilizar a terceros como Patreo on Buy Me a <whatever>?". Porque SO ya tiene nuestra fuerza de trabajo ludificando el trabajo y haciéndolo un juego de QA.

Comment: P.D. Insisto que considero que no creo que meter monedas en SO sea una buena idea, de hecho creo que es pésima (con tantos problemas que ya nos ha dado la reputación...), o quizás sería mucho de pensar. Sólo que todo surgió por una pregunta hace tiempo.